# Android can we save BufferedReader object in onpause

Tags: android, onpause

I am new to android. I need some help to work on my app. Basically I am trying to develop a quiz app. I have questions stored in a file. So my app reads each question from the file and displays it on the screen using InputStream and BufferedReader objects.

```
is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sampletest);
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

So now when user quits the app in the middle, I want my app to save is and br values(pointing to the question where the app left) and restore them again during the next app run. After doing some browsing, I learned that if we wish to persist the app state between different runs, onPause() is the one for such tasks. But can we save these is and br objects?How to save them in onPause().can someone help me out with a code snippet of saving these objects?

Thank you so much in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should write a code that saves the data into file, and on load parses the data from the saved file and creates the object.

onPause is not helpful here because like you said it is about app exit, so all the memory (and your objects) are lost..

edit:

if you are sure your app continues running in background, try to save the objects outside the activity:

Very rough example:

```
void onPause(...) {
    SomeSingleton.getInstance().setObjects(is, br);
}

void onCreate(...) {
    is =  SomeSingleton.getInstance().getIs();
    br =  SomeSingleton.getInstance().getBr();
}
```

Comment: K..but I read that onPause() is for that very purpose..persisting state b/w app runs..

Comment: If you are sure your app is continue running, you can use, for example, the following solution:

make some Singleton class, and save your objects there

Comment: Firstly,thank you..I mean " app b/w different runs" means when the app is closed and opened at same point later..so I don think singleton will be of use here..Will it still be useful?..

Comment: No, I agree in this case with answer and comments by Joseph Earl

Answer (score 0):

No. What you should do is save something simple like the position (question number) and a list of the answers that can be persisted in a bundle in `onSaveInstanceState`. You can then get these saved values from the Bundle in `onCreate`.

e.g.

```
private int position;
private ArrayList<String> answers;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        position = savedInstanceState.getInt("position");
        answers = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("answers");
    } else {
        answers = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    // This should load up the right question.
    displayQuestion(position);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("position", position);
    outState.putStringArrayList("answers", answers);
}
```

Comment: So should I save qno and when the app is started next time, I should parse the file until the particular qno is met?..no other way?...

Comment: Yes. It might be worth changing how you store your questions, e.g. separate files or an SQLiteDatabase so you can retrieve one question at a time. But if the file is not that large then just load them all at once.

Comment: thanks for takin ur time off in helping me.."loading all of them at once" do you mean should I add all the quesions from file to some list..and then loading the questions from list?

Comment: Yes, if your file is small load all of your questions once into a `List` of `Strings` or something similar, then just the question from the list when you need to display it.

Comment: yeah...that's what I thought of implementing it at first(lists)..I wish I could do that..but I was instructed not to do that..coz it adds overhead if the no of questions is too large...apart from lists any other way to store this questions that is much faster n less overhead kinda thing??...  sory for asking too many ques..

Comment: Store each question in a separate file or some other manner where you can just load the question you want each time.

Comment: k...by the way do lists really add too much overhead in case of large set of questions..its just dat I want to learn..